# Remove characters on paste jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the special characters on pasting a text into a textbox? For example, if I paste `12312-+(){}[];'`, it should only result in `12312` being shown.

I have tried something like this:

```
$F(#input).bind('paste', function(e) {
    var self = this;
    var val = $F(self).val();
    var regx = new RegExp(/^[0123456789]$/);
    if (!regx.test(val)) {
        val.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').replace(/[-+]/g, '')
        $F(self).val(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you use both constructor and regex literal? `new RegExp(/^[0123456789]$/)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `$F` is a reference to jQuery then you need to wrap the selector in quotes as it should be a string. You should also use the `on()` method as `bind()` is deprecated. `input` would also be a better event to use for your purpose.

The issue with your code is that you need to actually work with the outcome of the `replace()` call - which you currently don't do. You perform the operation, but do nothing with the resulting string that's returned.

Finally, you can tidy the logic by providing a function to `val()` which works with the current value and returns what you want to replace it with. Something like this:

```js
$('#input').on('input', function(e) {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/[^\d]/gi, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: But I have input type as number. Do I have to change it as text to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery you can run regex to replace all characters which arent digits, if needed i can look at a pure javascript version for you also in response to the 1st post where you asked if you need text type, you dont if you use my code below:

```
 $('#input').on('input', function(event) {
    var s = $('#myInput').val().toString();
    var x = s.replace(/[^\d]/gi, '');
    $('#myInput').val(x);
  })
```

to see my full example go here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zr5wfuvq/

alternatively using the 1st answer you just need to return v.toString().replace(...); adding the .toString() removes the need to change your input to text type. a bug of not doing this is pressing e or .. would remove the entire contents of your input otherwise. Though my understanding lacks the explanation to tell you why.